# How to insert text between characters in a EditText on Android?

Tags: android, insert, position, android-edittext, character

Im getting an Hour value from a database which I am working and I can't change it.

The value can be for example "1800" which means "18:00" or "930" which means "9:30". This value appears on a EditText.

So how can I insert the ":" in that value before it shows in the EditText.

Thanks!

Comment: you can make use of `split` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the format you provided, the last two characters must be minute, so you can substring it and add the ":" in the middle.

```
String str = "1800";
final int len = str.length();
String formattedStr = str.substring(0, len - 2) + ":" + str.substring(len - 2, len); // 18:00
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use setText[] with the character[] attribute

```
char[] your_addition = {':'};
//use setText(char[], int start, int length)
your_editext.setText(your_addition, 2, 1);
```

You can also check the length of your string to make sure that the value for int start is correct using 2 when the length is 4 and 1 when the length is 3.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

try to split your string which is getting set to edit text. use yourString.split(":");